# dictionary key values show only unique results instead all

Tags: python

i have `corpus_test` then i'm upgrade him to list with split by words. i need have 2 `dictionarys` from this and `len` of text words. problem is unique values. i need all of them, even duplicates.

```
corpus_test = 'cat dog tiger tiger tiger cat dog lion'
corpus_test = [[word.lower() for word in corpus_test.split()]]
word_counts = defaultdict(int)
for rowt in corpus_test:
    for wordt in rowt:
        word_counts[wordt] += 1



        index_wordso = dict((i, word) for i, word in enumerate(rowt))

        word_indexso = dict((word, i) for i, word in enumerate(rowt)) 

        v_countso = len(index_wordso)
```

my code give me right outputs with `index_wordso` and `v_countso`:

```
index_wordso
#{0: 'cat',
 1: 'dog',
 2: 'tiger',
 3: 'tiger',
 4: 'tiger',
 5: 'cat',
 6: 'dog',
 7: 'lion'}


v_countso
#8
```

but `word_indexso` (inverse `dict` to `index_wordso`) give's me not right output:

```
word_indexso
#{'cat': 5, 'dog': 6, 'tiger': 4, 'lion': 7}
```

that's give me only last values, not all. i need all 8 values

Comment: You could use a list of tuples, or maybe a list of dictionaries?

Comment: Dictionary keys are unique.  If they weren't you would be able to do `word_indexso['tiger']` and get a reasonable result.  (Should it return `2`, `3`, or `4`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys in a dictionary are unique, values are not. It's like a word dictionary: there can be multiple definitions of a word, but not multiple word listings.

A workaround is using a list of tuples:

```py
corpus_test = 'cat dog tiger tiger tiger cat dog lion'
corpus_test = [word.lower() for word in corpus_test.split()]
print([(a,b) for (a, b) in zip(corpus_test, range(len(corpus_test)))])
```

which results in

```py
[('cat', 0),
 ('dog', 1),
 ('tiger', 2),
 ('tiger', 3),
 ('tiger', 4),
 ('cat', 5),
 ('dog', 6),
 ('lion', 7)]
```

Keep in mind, though, that this is not a lookup table, and so you must loop through the elements (in some way) to find a speficic element.

Another method is to use a dictionary of lists:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

word_indexso = defaultdict(list)
corpus_test = 'cat dog tiger tiger tiger cat dog lion'.split()

for index, word in enumerate(corpus_test):
    word_indexso[word].append(index)

print(word_indexso)
```

which results in

```py
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'cat': [0, 5], 'dog': [1, 6], 'tiger': [2, 3, 4], 'lion': [7]})
```

which can be looked up with e.g. `word_indexso["cat"]` to get the list of numbers associated with the word.

Comment: hm. that's true, so i can't do anything with python? that's just a basics?

Comment: @germanjke I realise that my answer was not a real answer, sorry about that. With inspiration from AMC, see my updated answer.

Comment: @germanjke Also, Python is not a "basics" language :) You just have to think about the problem and which data structures would be best.